# Religious salutations in religious SE sites

Tags: discussion, edits, noise-reduction, religion-sites

Along with [this question on religious salutations on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47578/what-to-do-about-religious-salutations), since Islam.SE went through private beta, I need to know if the same policy holds there.

Some users get offended when I edit their religious salutations out, as they think they should/must be allowed. Their reasoning is that Islam.SE is a religious site and should be excluded from other SE sites' policy. I wanted to make sure that what I've been doing is right. My reasoning is that because it is an SE site, we have to follow the network policy.

Comment: Sounds like a case for their Meta IMO. If they decide they want to keep them, I don't think SE should overrule them.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why privileges are not (and should not be) transferred from site to site... Whats a valid edit on one site might be considered vandalism on another.

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags: Well, a user posted a question on Islam.meta and asked to avoid editing them. I was writing an answer to it as I am the one who edits those greetings there. I thought I had to ask here first.

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly a good question to ask here, too, as such things will come up on other SE  sites as well.

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags: While I agree with you, I think the "Low Noise, High Signal" applies on the whole SE site...and salutations, of whatever kind, are noise.

Comment: This is not a global Stack Exchange issue. Each religious site that sprouts up can have its own discussion on whether that community wants to allow something like that or not. It's not up to us here to decide that for them, as a lot of us here don't know anything about that community. All we can do is cast our general opinions about "salutations" which are already well documented in several questions here.

Comment: @Urist yeah. I agree in principle, and I probably wouldn't like to be active on a site where every post is preceded by a huge salutation. But when the salutations are so close to the site's topic, I think it needs to be left up to the community to decide.

Comment: @Lix: Of course you're capable of doing such a thing, but they all will be edited out. (evil grin)

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags: `So close to the site's topic`...ahm, so if I past a C++-Hello-Everyone code at the beginning of all my questions on SO, does that make it more appropriate? Just because it is related to the site's topic, doesn't make it less noise.

Comment: I would love to hear what the sites mod's have to contribute to this discussion...

Comment: @Lix it's in private beta, no mods yet.

Comment: @Urist the site's topic is a specific religion. If it's customary in that religion to precede everything you write with "in the name of...", it doesn't make sense to enforce a network policy on it. I'm all for editing it out on SE (and I do), but not here. We'll have to accept that some sites will have quirks, and not work exactly the way SO works

Comment: Another question here is whether the site is there to practice religion or discuss it.  If it is the latter (which I believe it is) then salutations should go just like user signatures on any other site...

Comment: @Lix that's a fair point. But that's a question for their Meta, too

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Enforcing such network-wide policies on a new site with a significant number of users without SE experience means you'll have a lot of explaining to do. We shouldn't just hand down those policies as immutable pieces of wisdom or absolute commands, we should always try to explain the reasoning behind those policies.

There are sometimes valid reasons to ignore site-wide policies on a specific site, I don't think that is the case here, but the network-wide policies are not absolute law, with a few exceptions like policies on abusive language or behaviour.

You'll have to convince the community that removing salutations benefits the site in the end, not just leave it at "it's a network-wide policy".

Comment: By making exceptions for a specific SE site, you've got some explaining to do too.  Why should a religious site be exempt from the rules?  Anyway, I think this is red herring; the example given at [the linked question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47578) is not a religious greeting at all, but merely an arabic language salutation.

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately, this should be left up to the local community to decide.

On the one hand, there is a network wide policy in place that forbids salutations for the sake of a better signal to noise ratio.

On the other hand, on a religion-related site, deleting out a salutation such as [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basmala) is fit to alienate new users who know nothing about the Stack Exchange system, for no real gain. That is a very strong case to make an exemption from the network wide policy.

However (as hinted by Mad Scientist in his answer), it might make sense for a SE representative to make the case for the network-wide policy and the reasonings behind it on the local Islam.SE Meta. Maybe they can be convinced of the value of editing them out, and educating new users about this.

Comment: Christianity and Judaism sites seem to work fine without salutations, I'm not convinced the religion factor is important here after all. But it's also not my decision to make.

Comment: @Mad yeah. I guess this is why it's an issue on Islam.SE:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basmala